# pip3 fails but pip works fine with virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I want to install virtualenv for python3.
I've been trying to figure this out for the past hour and had no luck.

```
root@XXXX:~# pip3 install virtualenv
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement virtualenv
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for virtualenv
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
root@XXXX:~# vim /root/.pip/pip.log
root@XXXX:~# pip install virtualenv
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-13.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.7MB): 1.7MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Successfully installed virtualenv
Cleaning up...
```

As you can see, pip works just fine, but pip3 times out.

According to the pip.log output from the failure, pip3 times out trying to request from pypi:

```
/usr/bin/pip3 run on Wed Dec  2 08:45:51 2015
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/: timed out
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/ when looking for download links for virtualenv
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: timed out
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for virtualenv
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  URLs to search for versions for virtualenv:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/: timed out
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/ when looking for download links for virtualenv
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement virtualenv
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_root...
No distributions at all found for virtualenv
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1178, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 277, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for virtualenv
```

Any tips as to how I can resolve this would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no virtualenv for pip3, but it is easy to set up a new environment to use python3

1. You install it with normal pip

`pip install virtualenv`

2. config the new virtualenv to use python3

`virtualenv -p python3 envname`

Comment: I had actually figured that out by the time you replied, but now trying to use pip in my virtualenv and i'm still getting time out errors. Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0c52a45208>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/cassandra-driver/

Comment: have you activated the environment and are you using `pip3` inside your environment?

Comment: i have activated the env and i'm using pip not pip3, maybe thats the problem? 

`pip --version` yields:
pip 7.1.2 from /var/virtualenvs/backend/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)

Comment: I am currently sitting at a windows. And everything is quirky with python. I can help you when I get home in a few hours

Comment: You should mark that one as correct open a new Question for your specific problem. It is not good when Questions change topic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34038946/pip-in-virtualenv-gets-connecttimeouterror